# WordPress header image loads way later than the rest of the page

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I've been working on a WordPress website lately, the (temporary) URL is https://temp.cwtranslation.com/. Yet whenever I load the page on my phone, the header image (on the homepage) appears about 5 seconds after the rest of the page has been loaded. This issue persists on other mobile devices. However, the images do load instantly on other pages.

I've tried reducing the image size, disabling cache (W3 Total Cache), optimizing images (reSmush.it) and incognito mode. Here's a [Screenshot of the missing header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4O0O.jpg). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the icon enough (hand with lightning bolt) or do you want the text next to it, too?

Comment: Hey @Insomnia88, 
Thanks for replying. I see now that I misspoke, I meant the area below the header. I've been tinkering around with it the last few days (I'm using WP Super Cache now), but the image seems to keep having troubles with appearing.
It happens every now and then, both on my phone and desktop now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why this helped, but it did:

In Elementor, there was a movement effect set to 'none'. I changed it to standard, and the problem seems to be fixed.